# Dynamic Eclipse Project Value in Run Configuration

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-jdt

I am dealing with a repository of Java and C++ modules that is configured as follows:

**Repo Structure**

```
Repo/
- ModuleA/
  - src/
    - ...
  - ModuleA.launch
  - ...
- ModuleB/
  - ... # same as above.
- ...
```

My concern is with the definition of the launch script (IE: `ModuleA.launch` in the above); specifically, the `PROJECT_ATTR` value of these scripts.  If we were to open up these launch scripts, they contain an entry like this:

**ModuleA.launch**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.localJavaApplication">
<!-- or <launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.cdt.launch.applicationLaunchType> -->
...
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROJECT_ATTR" value="ModuleA"/>
<!-- or <stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.cdt.launch.PROJECT_ATTR" value="ModuleA"/> -->
...
</launchConfiguration>
```

The above has the problem that, if the module is not checked out as *exactly* ModuleA, the run script will not find the project (which is fragile).  As far as I can tell, this field can't be populated with variables (IE: `value="${project_name}"`).

Is there any way to tell the launch script to use the containing project for the Project value (or any reasonable workaround that results in a similar experience)?  The Eclipse version is Kepler SR2 (and cannot be changed), if that is relevant.

Comment: You are talking about Java, but reguarding to you XML file you are using Eclipse CDT that is for C/C++. Aren't you confusing something ?

Comment: I've looked inside CDT code, this attribute is setted in the class CMainTab2 (since CDT 7.3 otherwise CMainTab), in the function `performApply()` (package is org.eclipse.cdt.launch.ui). It's setted when you are in the window to configure the launch configuration (run>Run configurations). Here you can change the code to write `"${project_name}"` if you want. But be careful when you change Eclipse code it may cause problem when you will update it. Moreover I'm not sure there is a variable `project_name` (or with another name) containing the project name...

Comment: @vincrichaud The repository actually deals with both C++ and Java projects (I just happened to copy the XML from a C++ module.  Regardless, the behavior mentioned is true of both Java and C++ launch scripts.  Sorry for the confusion; I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: @vincrichaud At this point, I think the bounty is going to expire without attracting an answer that solves the problem (without modifying Eclipse sources).  If you want to word your investigation into the form of an answer and state that it can be used to solve the problem for CDT (and state that likely a similar solution exists for JDT; no need to investigate it further), then I will accept it.

Comment: I will put it as answer cause it will be more readable and complete. But not sure it deserve to be accepted since it does not really answer your question...

Comment: @vincrichaud It provides a solution to the problem.  It isn't perfect, but it seems like at this point it is simply a deficiency of exported Eclipse launch scripts and there *isn't* a perfect solution.  I'll check the Eclipse backlog later to see if there is a bug report against it or not, and submit one if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Investigation :**

Looking at the CDT code, this attribute is set in only one place. It's in the package `org.eclipse.cdt.launch.ui` int the class [`CMainTab2`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/launch/org.eclipse.cdt.launch/src/org/eclipse/cdt/launch/ui/CMainTab2.java) (for CDT version over 7.3, otherwise it's in [`CMainTab`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/launch/org.eclipse.cdt.launch/src/org/eclipse/cdt/launch/ui/CMainTab.java)), at the line 344, in the function `performApply()`.

This class defines the tab called "main" in the UI window used to configure a Run Configuration (or a Debug Configuration). As shown in the image below:
[image: Main Tab]

The function `performApply()` is called every time you refresh this tab (so when you open or close it), and when you click the "apply" button (at the bottom left of the window).

This function just set some attribute in the launch configuration. One of these is the project name (`ICDTLaunchConfigurationConstants.ATTR_PROJECT_NAME`). This attribute is set to the value of `fProjText.getText()`, which is the text box in the window shown below:

[image: Project Field]

This text box is auto-filled when you create a Run configuration (or Debug configuration) with the last built project's name.

***Note:*** I did not look at the JDT code but I suppose it's the same

---

**Solutions**

***1)*** Change nothing, because it may be intentionally like this (even if I don't know why). ***Note:*** *I think this value could be wrong only if you modify it, so I think that's why it's hard written in the `.launch` script.*

***2)*** You can modify the Eclipse code to not use the text box value, but something like `"${project_name}"`. ***Note:*** I do not recommended this, because it will be harder to update your project to follow eclipse updates.

***2 bis)*** Instead of rewriting the Eclipse code, extend the `CMainTab2` class to override the `performApply()` method to set the attribute to `"${project_name}"`.

***3)*** Do not modify any code, and every time you create a launch configuration (run or debug), modify the text box value to ${project_name}. (*But it will be laborious to re-enter this every time*)

***Note :*** *I don't know if there exists a variable such as `project_name` that you can call in the .launch script. So maybe all these potential solutions are not possible*

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  My only comment would be for this statement: "I think this value could be wrong only if you modify it, so I think that's why it's hard written in the .launch script." - When developers check out repositories, they often check them out under different names than the original project (IE: if they are working on Issue 123 on ModuleA, they might check it out as "ModuleA-123").  So, while it is a modification of the project, it's not necessarily egregious in nature.

Comment: I didn't think about this case (surely because I don't know it since I'm still a junior in IT). I suggest you to submit your problem to the eclipse community. btw, I've rewrite it to be presented more like a solution and less like a note. btw2, thx for your review